# Set app for launch

Tags: android, button, colors

I'm a beginner developer in android. I have a question. I want to create a menu that change a color of a text. Also I have a button that open an app. And I want with a menu to change the app that will open. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Can you show us your attempts to provide context for your code structure? And can you please clarify exactly what your difficulty is in implementing what you want?

Answer (score 2):

To change the text-color, i think what you are looking for is a color picker library like this https://github.com/yukuku/ambilwarna

For the app thing, you can make a list of apps e.g. like that

```
final Intent mainIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
mainIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
final List pkgAppsList = context.getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities( mainIntent, 0);
```

i don't know exactly what you want to end up with, but this may help.

Comment: Let me explain better. When I set the color blue in the color picker it will set the text blue. And the same to open another application